# List Items created in foreach not displaying in partial view MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am editing this question due to discoveries on my own and a realization that the original question isn't correct. The controller looks as such:

```
public class TabController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main Action for returning the tabs
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult BuildTabs(string jobNumber)
    {
        List<Tab> tabList = new List<Tab>();
        int newJobNumber = Convert.ToInt32(jobNumber);
        var indTabs = CompdataSurveysBusiness.DataPassThrough.GetIndustrybyJobNumber(newJobNumber);

        foreach (var t in indTabs)
        {
            Tab tab = new Tab() { Id = t.IndustryId, Name = t.IndustryId.ToString(), Visible = true, Url = jobNumber.ToString() };

            tabList.Add(tab);
        }

        return PartialView("_Tabs", tabList);
    }
}
```

Here is the jQuery that sends data to the controller action when a jsTree node is selected.

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    //code block for enabling accept and submit buttons once a job is selected in the treeview
    $("input").removeAttr("disabled");

    //conditional statement to disable the selection of parent (Job Type) Nodes
    if (data.node.children.length > 0) {
        $tree.jstree(true).deselect_node(data.node);
        //            $tree.jstree(true).toggle_node(data.node);
    };

    //conditional statement to disable the selected node
    if (data.node.children.length <= 0) {
        $tree.jstree(true).disable_node(data.node);
    }

    //not allow any other node to be selected
    //        $tree.jstree(true).deselect_all(true);

    //section for passing the ID of selected node to server for processing
    var id = data.node.id;
    var url = '@Url.Action("BuildTabs", "Tab", new { jobNumber = "-1" })';
    url = url.replace("-1", id);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
```

And here is the partial view's HTML.

```
@model List<AnalyticsTool.Models.Tab>
<div id="tabsWrapper">
    <ul id="ulTab">
        @foreach (var t in Model)
        {
            <li class="liTab"><a id="@t.Id" class="aTab" href="@t.Url">@t.Name</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

So essentially when a tree node is selected I need to render a partial view of tabs. What I am not sure about, as I am new to MVC, is how to render the partial view on my main view.

Comment: You're calling your partial view at the Index view right?

Comment: This previous comment of mine was incorrect. The action is being called in jQuery so I am not sure how to render the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a empty list in the `_Tabs`.

```
 @Html.Partial("_Tabs", new List<AnalyticsTool.Models.Tab>())
```

You should pass in a model with the `Tab` list. The way you have it setup now you should 
use

`@{Html.Action("Index", "CONTROLLER NAME");}`

Comment: I have edited the above code to fix the passing of an empty list and just call the action of the correct controller, however, the list items are still not being rendered as before. When debugging I can step through and the correct values from the model are being passed but nothing inside the foreach of the partial view gets rendered. Could it be something else in the markup of the View? There are other elements not shown in my code example above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to treat the partial as a child action. Partials don't have their own context. They inherit the context of the main view and only have access to data that that main view had. What you want is a child action instead. Your index action basically already is a child action since you're returning a partial view. However, you should decorate it with `[ChildActionOnly]` to prevent direct URL access to it, since it only ever returns a partial view (no layout).

That said, all you need to do then, really is just change your `Html.Partial` call to:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "ControllerIndexIsIn")
```

That will then cause your index action to actually be run and the partial view to be parsed with the results.

Comment: I have updated my code to use Html.Action and updated the code in this post as well but i still have the same issue. I can step through the partial and the foreach loop appears to be working but no list items are rendered. Any other ideas of what could cause this? Maybe other mark up on the page?

Comment: Your updated code looks good. Check the method you're using to get the tabs in the first place in your child action. Are you sute you're getting something back from that?

Comment: Yeah I am getting everything back as I should. Whenever I debug, the foreach loop in the partial has all the correct values as well but it is just not being rendered on the page.

Comment: Okay. Well if you can see the foreach loop running in the partial, then it's getting output. The only thing i can imagine is that you've got some client-side script that's clearing it out after the fact. Check the actual generated source (view source, dont just inspect the HTML with the browser's development tools). Is the list there? If so, then start looking at your JavaScript.

Comment: I was completely incorrect with all comments regarding original question. The reason for it never showing is the action was being called in the Index view when data was empty and then again (correctly) from jQuery. So when the correct call was made it passed data to the partial but it was never rendered on the Index view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call @html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller") this will call the controller action and return the resultant partial view, the way you are calling it passed in an empty model which has nothing to loop through to render